# Hide a Field in junction object

Tags: record-type, junction-object

In Account Object, I have 2 different record type - type1 and type2. There is a Junction Object call Associated Location between Locations and Accounts and I want to hide a checkbox field in Associated Location -object for Account record type2. When a user is creating a new relation between type2 Account and location, the checkbox won't be visible at all. How can I do it?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a ["**page layout**"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layoutcreate.htm&type=5) for each of the **RecordTypes** and then hide that field from the desired page.

**RecordTypes** can be assign to pages and there is where you can make the changes for your different layouts.

Check how to do this [**here**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_record_types.htm&type=5)

You could also go by User Profile.

Go to **Set Up** --> Search for , **Field Accessibility** --> Select **Associated Location** and the Select the Profile you don't want to be able to see that field. Select the field and uncheck the "**Visible**" ... but for your scenario you probably need to build two page layouts.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I want to hide it for some record type and a record type can be available for many profiles.

Comment: Then use my first solution. Create a page layout and assign that page to the record type. You can also assign that page to profiles. On that page keep the fields that those user are suppose to see  and problem solved :) ..

Comment: But the record type is in the Account Object and the field is in the Associated Location Junction Object. How I can assign the page from junction object to another object?

Comment: How are your users viewing the field on the Associated Location from the Account Object? Are they viewing this field on the related list that is part of the Account object? How are you exposing the field from the Associated Location object on the Account object?